# Measuring FPS/Performance in Xcode/Iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, performance, extjs

I am running a Sencha Touch application and I am wondering what the best way to measure my FPS while running my app on a device from Xcode? Specifically I have an infinitely scrolling facebook-like wall and I am trying to measure my scrolling performance.

Answer (score 32):

You can use instruments for this! Tap and hold the play button in Xcode and press 'profile' and it will open the instruments app. Use the Core Animation Template. It'll show you FPS to test your scroll performance.

Comment: How to measure FPS with Core Animation when it only shows number of redraws? :(

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this tool for measuring FPS on both iOS and Android devices, simultaneously and you dont even need a mac (PC/linux would do!)

https://www.gamebench.net/en/content/gamebench-desktop-profiler

Answer (score 1):

You can use the native CADisplayLink to count frames as they are rendered on the screen. [FPSCounter](https://github.com/konoma/fps-counter) does that.